# Get rental price from YouTube Data API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm currently using the YouTube Data API v3 for videos and I'd like to get pricing information from the API. I couldn't find anything regarding that in the API. Is there another API for this kind of information that I'm not aware of or some undocumented parameter?

Here's an example request to get information about a movie that can be rented and bought on YouTube:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=API_KEY_HERE&part=snippet&id=wz43PZMOrAM
```

There's a price visible on the site itself but no trace of it in the API:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wz43PZMOrAM&app=desktop

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Facing a similar problem and would love to be able to query this info

Comment: Unfortunately not. Doesn't seem possible or something they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is beyond the Youtube Data API's [scope](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/). You can't fetch that information using the Youtube API yet.

Comment: Is this still the case? The documentation isn't very helpful for seeing if this functionality has since been added or not